# Excel Connection String Opens Source Workbook If 'Locked for Editing'

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a dashboard which pulls in data from various sources on a network. I have setup Excel 2010 Microsoft Queries to pull in tables of data (used the ribbon menu to set this up).

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=S:\2017 process\2017 main tracker.xlsm;Mode=Read;Extended Properties="Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;HDR=YES;MODE=READ;READONLY=TRUE;";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False
```

However, if someone on the network has the file locked open for editing. Then the workbook im trying to connect to will open (in read-only). This is undesirable. I want to pull in the data, without the source workbook opening at all.

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening? I have added `MODE=READ;READONLY=TRUE;` to the extended properties of the connection string but still no luck.

Any Help is appreciated,

Calico

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be to copy the file to a temp directory and delete after extracting the data.

Comment: Hello Karl, thank you for the suggestion. However, I am pulling in data from about 8 different sources. Plus this dashboard will be used by many people on the network throughout the week (wanting to pull in the most recent data). So creating copies would be fairly laborious. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see, I figured that out right after I posted that this was probably not what you were going for since you could open a read only copy anyhow.

I just attempted get data--> from excel file and imported a sheet to a new book.  Then I opened the source file (not over network though, same user same pc) edited a little and Refresh worked fine and no issues about the file being open.

Perhaps this is because of your office 2010?

Comment: No Problem. Hmm thanks for testing, however, I think it may be caused by different users accessing the same file over a network. I will test it on my end (lock out a file for editing on the network) and then try to query it for data. I'm also looking into using VBA to setup a OLEDB connection to see if it makes a difference! Thanks